# Как скомпилировать Slint (Rust) без отображения консоли

Tags: windows, gui, rust, cargo

Нужно скомпилировать [Slint](https://slint.dev/) приложение на Rust, но при открытии .exe файла помимо окна с интерфейсом вылезает консоль. Возможно ли скомпилировать без показа консоли?
Компилировал командой `cargo build --release`

Comment: `#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]` https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/runtime.html#the-windows_subsystem-attribute